# Difference between tibbles and data frames when using selfwritten function

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

What i tried is the following:

```
identical_length_values <- function(x){
  nchar(x[,1]) == nchar(x[,2])
}

a <- "abc"
b <- "cba"
c <- "abc"
d <- "cbaa"
df1 <- data.frame(a, b)
df2 <- data.frame(c, d)
list1 <- list(df1, df2)

names(which(sapply(list1, identical_length_values)))
```

which gives me what i want:

```
[1] "hello"
```

If those data frames are tibbles though, i get the following:

```
df1 <- as_tibble(data.frame(a, b))
df2 <- as_tibble(data.frame(c, d))
list1 <- list(hello = df1, bye = df2)

names(which(sapply(list1, identical_length_values)))

[1] "hello.a"
```

Why does my function add the column name of the first column here, seperated by a point? I can't think of a scenario, where this is what i would want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference lies in how dataframes handle subsetting one-column dataframe by default vs that of tibbles.

When you subset a dataframe with only one column it drop's it's dimension and you get a vector back.

```
df1 <- data.frame(a, b)
df1[, 1]
#[1] "abc"

class(df1[, 1])
#[1] "character"
```

When you subset tibble with one column you get a tibble back.

```
df1 <- as_tibble(data.frame(a, b))
df1[, 1]
# A tibble: 1 x 1
 # a    
 # <chr>
#1 abc  
class(df1[, 1])
#[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

Hence, for dataframes there are no column names in the data to be appended in the final output so you get only list names back.

```
df1 <- data.frame(a, b)
df2 <- data.frame(c, d)
list1 <- list(hello = df1, bye = df2)
sapply(list1, identical_length_values)
#hello   bye 
# TRUE FALSE
```

However, for tibbles the column names are still there so it gets appended in the result.

```
df1 <- as_tibble(data.frame(a, b))
df2 <- as_tibble(data.frame(c, d))
list1 <- list(hello = df1, bye = df2)
sapply(list1, identical_length_values)
#hello.a   bye.c 
#   TRUE   FALSE
```

---

If you use `[[` instead of `[` it will always return a vector back and you'll not face this issues.

```
identical_length_values <- function(x){
  nchar(x[[1]]) == nchar(x[[2]])
}
```